# How to display a text in android after a button click in android?

Tags: android, autocomplete, toast

After making an auto complete text view once the user click the OK button(which i made) i wanted the application to display the contents of selected text in auto complete as a button or as a text view..I find only Toast class for this..which will last only for a short time..Is there any other way of doing it??

Comment: Hey can you more explain your question?

Comment: Y?? Ur textview isnt working??? tv.setText???

Comment: do you want to use textview in place of toast ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, fjust write onClick method in OnClickListener as

```
btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View view)
   {
       String text=mEdit.getText();
       mText.setText(text);
   }
});
```